Modify table with a one to many non-equi join
I have a table which contains a 'group_id' 'start_time' and 'end_time' column and another table containing the look up values for that table: 'group_id' and 'time'.
In SQL I would have a SELECT query like
FROM
    a
    LEFT JOIN b 
    ON a.group_id = b.group_id AND a.start_time <= b.time AND a.end_time >= b.time

However I can't work out how to perform a similar transformation in Power BI.
What should I be doing here?
